# Parse json response in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am beginner and learning javascript and never came across parsing json array. I have following string

```
[{"_id":"5810abfec95a8743ec237fab","credentials":[{"_id":"5810abfec95a8743ec237fab","username":"sam"}]}]
```

I tried following,

```
     //using following middle-ware as well
     let app = express();
     const collectioName = "credentials";
     app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

     //i get 'result' from one of query from mongodb
     let response = JSON.parse(result);
     console.log("got res " +response.credentials);
```

I also tried to get data in following way

```
 for (var i=0; i<response['credentials'].length; i++){
       console.log("got res " +response['credentials'][i]);
   }
```

I need to get the username and its value from above json response.
I want to know what is correct way to get data from such json response.

Please suggest

Comment: You JSON is an array, so probably all your accesses will start with `response[0].credentials`.

Comment: When i tried `response[0].credentials` it gave me output as ` [object Object]` .

Comment: Because this again is an array, which you have to access basically in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var data=response[0].credentials;
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i]._id);
  console.log(data[i].username);
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7ya1L97/)

Comment: It works, so is this the most efficient way to access data?

Comment: @Sohan,yes,because we have an array called `credentials` and must to iterate it.

Comment: @Sohan, another method is using `forEach` function. Here is an solution: https://jsfiddle.net/j7ya1L97/2/

Answer (score 3):

After looking at above answer i got some clue and i think this should work as well, this save time of iteration for me as the datastructure will return only one json object for respective credentials match (as same credentials cannot be there in DB).

```
   let response = JSON.parse(result);
   var data=response[0].credentials;
   let username = data[0].username;
   let password = data[0].password;
   console.log("username : " +username + "password : " +password );
```

Comment: Yes..if you have only one user, there's no need to iterate.

Comment: A simpler method is here : https://jsfiddle.net/j7ya1L97/3/ .You must return json without array.